# ManagedObject Seems to Lose Its Class Type, or Becomes a Different Type of Object

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios4

I'm experiencing the oddest behavior with a CoreData managed object.  In my viewDidLoad method I do the following:

```
    NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uuid = %@", self.imageUUID];
    NSFetchRequest *imageFetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [imageFetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSEntityDescription *imageEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    [imageFetchRequest setEntity:imageEntity];
    error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [[appDelegate managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:imageFetchRequest error:&error];

    tagImage = (Image *)[array objectAtIndex:0];
    assert([tagImage isKindOfClass:[Image class]]);
```

The assertion passes.  This particular view is a TableViewController and in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I need to check some of the Image properties.  Anytime I access a property of tagImage, the application fails so I added another assertion as follows in this method:

```
assert([tagImage isKindOfClass:[Image class]]);
```

This time, the assertion fails.  I have no idea what would be making the tagImage object change types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are retaining the array or the managed objects ? It might happen that there are somehow released and that's why you have an error ?

Comment: Are you talking about the array I get back from the imageFetchRequest?  I originally was releasing it after I got the image out, but was running into EXEC_BAD_ACCESS because of that.  So I removed that.  As far as I can tell, I'm never releasing that array at the moment.

Comment: Yepp - this could be the problem. The array executeFetchRequest returns is an autoreleased object so you must not release it. However if you would like to use the array, and any object it has outside your method, then make sure you retain it. (Then later on release it when you don't need it anymore ... (dealloc perhaps))

Comment: @Moszi - I removed the autorelease from the imageFetchRequest and I get the same results.  Should I also make the array an instance variable and retain it?

Comment: @mplappert - tagImage is retained via @property (nonatomic, retain) in the header and then it is synthesized in the implementation.  I've tried using both self.tagImage and just tagImage always getting the same results.  Is there a different way to retain a variable?

Comment: @Gregg: It only gets retained if you use `self.tagImage = [array objectAtIndex:0];`. Once again, Memory Management Programming Guide is definitely required reading and explains it all!

Comment: @Gregg - mplappert is right. you need to retain the tagImage. No need to do with the array anything - sorry for not observing this earlier.
you need to do a self.tagImage = [array objectAtIndex:0]; because the way you do it you access the ivar not the property so the tagImage is NOT retained your way. By using the self.tagImage construct you are accessing the property and it will automatically retain the tagImage ;)
( Also make sure you remove the assertions - and just use the properties of the managed object ... )

Comment: Ok, so again, I've tried self.tagImge = [array objectAtIndex:0] and tagImage is retained via the @property in the header.  Same results. I have now added [self.tagImage retain] after I get it from the array, and it works fine now.

Comment: @Gregg - [self.tagImage retain] is not correct :( - you are doing some release or autorelease additionally which causes this problem ;) - but you are on the right track ;)

Comment: Yea, I think I got it, although I swear I was doing this in the beginning and it wasn't working.  Oh well, happy to be through it.  All the explanations here helped.  As does the docco.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Image` class is definitely included in your build target.  I've seen instances where a fetch request returned vanilla `NSManagedObjects` rather than my own custom subclass because I had not included the class in the Logic Tests target I was running at the time.

As an aside, convention dictates you should be prefixing your class names with a two letter prefix of your choice (so something like MZImage in this case) to reduce the chances of a class name conflict.  There's a fairly good chance of running into a class name conflict with a class name of `Image`.